# Structuring Node API (express, mongodb, mongoose) For Conditionally Returned Values Based On User Type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, api-design

I'm building a REST API using Node with express, mongodb, and mongoose.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this. An endpoint that returns object values conditionally based off of the users role (available in the request, like `USER` or `ADMIN`).

As a standard user (`USER`), your response may look like this
`{id: "123", email: "test@test.com"}`

Whereas the response for an admin (`ADMIN`) would look like `{id: "123", email: "test@test.com", password: "abc"}`

Also, what is the best way to protect values on patch requests so that some keys can only be updated by users of a specific role. Is there a good solution to do this with mongoose (preferably using mongoose schema, to reduce redundancy)? If not, what would be the best way to incorporate a json validation library?

I've found plenty of documentation online for building REST APIs with this stack, but I was unable to find any that address my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mongoose doesn't provide this feature out of the box. I believe you have to do it manually. Although, you can make use of module like [schema-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/schema-utils) to do validation.

If I were you I would do something like this:

- Use some kind of authentication method.
- Create a property named `role` in mongoose `User` schema. Where role can be admin/user etc.
- Create a middleware to check if the current user is admin.
  Ex: `app.post('/', auth.isAdmin, (req, res) => {})`. Here `isAdmin` middleware check if the role is admin then proceed to next middleware.
- I would also populate `req.user` object with the current logged in user's data.

So, my code would be something like this:

```
app.patch('/email', auth.isAdmin, (req, res) => { DO UPDATE HERE });
```

Another example:

```
app.get('/user/:id', auth.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.role === 'admin') { DO STUFF }
  eles { DO STUFF }
})
```

Not sure if this would help you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in, they should assigned a a signed (readable but unchangeable) or encrypted (non readable and non changeable) jwt using a private key. Then with every call to the API they should be sending this in the Authorization header.  Decrypt on the backend with every call and you will be able to see the correct permission that you can trust has not been modified.

https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you can use JWT to store arbitrary user data. I'm more concerned with how to structure the mongoose schema (if possible) to return data conditionally based on user role. Also setting which values can be updated during a patch request based on the users role.